# Insert GRIDLINES in PowerPoint 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

Is it possible to insert GRIDLINES (not guidelines) in PowerPoint 2011? If so, how can this be done? 
Edit:
I'm looking for gridlines, as outlined in this [post](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/interface/gridlines-ppt2013.html).

Comment: what is the difference between guidelines and gridlines?

Answer (score 2):

1. Table Layout > New [choose range]
2. Table Style: No Style_Table Grid

Then stretch the table to fit your slide

[image]

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for. You are essentially inserting a table, not gridlines and I'd rather not insert anymore objects than necessary on the slide. But thanks for the hack.

Comment: I suspect the true answer is 'wait for Office Mac 2015"

Comment: Yea, I don't think it's in 2011 :(